# Practical application of the Drude model

Tags: solid-state-physics, electrons, electrical-resistance

I am trying to gain a better understanding of the [Drude model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drude_model).

I understand that the Drude model is used to look at movements of electrons with in a material.

My question is, what, if any, are the practical applications of the Drude model?

Comment: Personally I like the model for several reasons. First, it gives a (relatively) quantitative picture for why the ubiquitous Ohm's law is true, and second of all it explains the (classical) Hall effect. More so, it provides a pretty good starting point for more complicated (mesoscopic) transport phenomena, such as the Shubnikov de Haas effect and even the integer quantum hall effect.  It gives you a picture to start from, and make adjustments to until it becomes more realistic. But application wise, I'd say the first two.